# What clients use version number "2" and version number "1" in their block headers?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-hardware

Is Bitcoin Core the only protocol that uses these version numbers?

Does anyone know what ABC and Unlimited use?

Is there a place where I can see the raw version numbers for each client easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitcoin clients no longer use version 2 or version 1 in the block headers. Block version is now defined as per [BIP-9](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0009.mediawiki), and miners use specific bits in the block version number to signal their support for specific soft-forks in the bitcoin protocol. The top 3 bits of the blocks must be 001, so the range of actually possible nVersion values is from 0x20000000 to 0x3FFFFFFF, both inclusive.

Comment: What! why must the first 3 bits be 001? Thanks for the reply. And also, yea, I am looking at the Bitcoin-ABC code, and there does seem to be a lot of different numbers inside of it.

Comment: According to BIP-9, "When a block nVersion does not have top bits 001, it is treated as if all bits are 0 for the purposes of deployments." Thus, if the top 3 bits are not set as 001, miner will not be able to indicate his support for active proposals.

Comment: Thanks, of  course I read BIP 9 and I realized the reasons for it